# Angular 2 AoT compile causes application issues and works fine in JiT

Tags: angular, angular2-aot, angular-compiler-cli

I've followed the Angular 2 example from:
 
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html

After compiling the application using ngc AoT the routing doesn't work, it just stays on the same page and nothing happens.

Since the application does load it's too strange to even think of something that might be wrong when JiT compiling with tsc works and AoT compiling with ngc not.

I dont think pasting bits of code will help here but I was wondering if you know of any tool or debug feature I can use when the app is in AoT mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the uglify plugin used by rollup.

Using the configuration found here: https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/config/webpack.prod.js solved the problem.